# Changing environment variables after a call to subprocess.call

Tags: python, environment-variables, subprocess

Does altering an environment variable after a call to subprocess.call affect the environment seen by the call?

I'm basically looking to do something like this:

```
main.py:
for i in range(1,trials):
    os.putenv('trial', str(i))
    subprocess.call(foo.py)


foo.py:
    trial = os.getenv('trial')
    ...do stuff with trial...
```

foo.py is a file I can't change, so I can't just make it take in a command line argument.
Is there a race condition that I need to worry about, or am I guaranteed that the i'th call to foo.py has an environment where trial=i?

Comment: Yes, it does. (short version)

Comment: I'm afraid of answering questions because of all the hate you can get for even suggesting an alternative solution but, IF you want to make sure that the environment variable stays the same over a X ammount of commands, perhaps you should look into using `subprocess.Popen()` and redirect `stdin` + `stdout` and create a function call into a class object that you can "talk" to. calling one command, wait for it, send another command via stdin (assuming you've opned a shell and not just a command, because subprocess will die after a command, that's what it was designed to do IIRC :) It's only a tip

Comment: using environment variables as an IPC is not really a good idea